# Hidding checkbox inside a JQM checkboxgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a control group with checkboxes that I want them to be hidden initially, which I achieved with css, during runtime I would like to show those checkboxes at a certain time, but only from the control group that I specify because there are many of them on the page.

The problem that I'm having is to select the visual checkbox since it is being rendered as a "::after" text and I don't know how to select it using JQuery.

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" id="test-list">
   <label for="id1">
      <a href="#" onclick="alert('The list item has been clicked.'); event.stopPropagation(); return false;">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p>Description Text</p>
   </a>
   </label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="id1" />
</div>
```

**will render as:**

```
<div class="ui-checkbox">
   <label for="id1" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-btn-inherit ui-btn-icon-left ui-checkbox-off ui-first-child">
      <a href="#" onclick="alert('Clicked'); event.stopPropagation(); return false;" class=" ui-link">
         <h2>Title</h2>
         <p>Description</p>
      </a>
      ::after <!-- This is what renders as the checkbox -->
   </label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="id1" name="p1">
</div>
```

I tried a few tricks but can't select the **"::after"** which is what draws the checkbox inside the list.

```
$("#test-list label").first().next()
$("#test-list label").children().eq(0).next()
```

The css when the page loads to hide them:

```
.ui-btn.ui-checkbox-off:after, .ui-btn.ui-checkbox-on:after
{
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery cannot access pseudo elements like `:after` because they are not really in the DOM. You might get what you want by adding and removing a class that hides the `:after` element. First create a new CSS class:

```
.hiddenCheck:after {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Then apply it to the `<label>` that jQM creates for the checkbox:

```
$("#id1").parents(".ui-checkbox").find("label").toggleClass("hiddenCheck");
```

NOTE: different selectors can get you there (e.g. closest(), etc.).

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ba66h/)**

Click the button to hide/show the checkbox...

Comment: Excellent! Pity these checkboxes didn't behave well during my tests on a few cell phones so my guess is that is not a good design for mobile, I might try to achieve a similar effect with "multi-select" list items instead of checkboxes but that's something for another thread in case I don't manage to get working. Thanks a lot!